# ListView on seperate view not updating - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a UserControl (ReportView) that has a ListView connected to a ViewModel (ReportViewModel). That ViewModel creates an observable collection dynamically, which in turn updates the ListView. Now on another UserControl (EmailView), I copied the same ListView from the ReportView and connected the UserControl to the same ReportViewModel as its DataContext:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:ReportViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

So the UserControls both have the exact same code and controls. The ReportView has a button, that when pressed just updates the ObservableCollection in the ReportViewModel code. On ReportView, I can see the ListView updating but when I switch to the EmailView, the ListView is empty. I switch back to ReportView and it's all still there. It seems the ListView on the EmailView is grabbing the empty ObservableCollection list but not updating itself when it is filled with data. How can I get it to update?

Comment: `UserControl` shouldn't have its own datacontext, it should expose the datacontext of view, where it's hosted

Comment: I believe the statement `<ViewModels:ReportViewModel/>` should be creating a new instance that's why you don't see the list. As mentioned by @PavelAnikhouski - you need to bind the data context of view to user control

Comment: I think you're right, but how would I achieve this?

Comment: It seems to be the ItemsSource of the ListView. If i remove the XAML above from each UserControl and create a single instance of ReportViewModel in the MainWindow code behind, neither ListView box has its ItemsSource set because it cannot see the instance of the ReportViewModel (which creates an instance of the ObservableCollection list in its constructor). I am unsure why the binding is not working in <ListView x:Name="ReportListView" ItemsSource="{Binding UserList}">

Comment: If these two views are otherwise disconnected, you could share the one instance of your viewmodel in a decoupled manner. Make your viewmodel a resource or a singleton in an IoC container.

Comment: @IainBlackwood: So what's the `DataContext` of the `UserControls` after you have removed `<ViewModels:ReportViewModel/>` from the XAML?

Comment: It seems I was creating more than one instance of the ReportViewModel. Once I found out where, I removed them and now everything works as expected!